# Spark Dataframe write to mysql, can it write as varchar instead of TEXT

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, dataframe

By default Spark Dataframe will write to mysql as TEXT type for the String type value. Can we specify it as varchar, since we want to do indexing on that field?

Thanks ahead!